# gambling with increased chance of winning each loss

Tags: probability

If you were to start out with a 2% chance of winning a prize at the casino but each time you lost you were granted an additional 2% chance of winning, what would be the odds that you lost enough to reach a 70% chance of winning.

So say you start gambling with a 2% chance to win and you lose, so now you have a 4% chance to win.
now with that 4% chance of winning you lose again, so now you have a 6% chance.
but you lose again so now you have an 8% chance to win.
and you lose again so now you have a 10% chance, and so fourth.

What would be the odds that you lost so many times that you were able to reach a 70% chance of winning.

Comment: what happens when you win, it resets back to 2% or stays at the current level?

Comment: The odds are 100%, eventually you will reach it. Maybe you wanted to ask something else?

Comment: My guess is, it's supposed to ask how many rounds you're expected to play.

Comment: when you win it resets, but that is besides the point. im just asking what are the odds that you could lose so many times that eventually you would have a 70% chance of winning, the odds could not be 100% because after 25 rolls or so you will start rolling to win with over 50% chances of winning, and still losing over 10 times in a row.

Comment: say you're at a slot machine, and each time you pull the lever and lose you are granted an extra 2% chance. so starting at 0% chance you pull and lose, so now you have a 2% chance and you pull and lose, so now you have a 4% chance and you pull and lose, so now there is a 6% chance of winning, but you lose so you keep losing and with each pull having this percent chance of winning so then you move onto having as such 8% 10% 12% 14% 16% 18% 20% 22% 24% 26% 28% 30% 32% 34% 36% 38% 40% 42% 44% 46% 48% 50% 52% 54% 56% 58% 60% 62% 64% 66% 68% 70%. what would be the odds that this happened.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell Oh so the question is not what the chance is that this happens eventually, but all in a row without ever resetting?

Comment: basically asking for what $\frac{1}{2^{35}}$ is? (also s/o to that r6 alpha pack roll chance that is exactly the same context as what you're asking)

Comment: lol SirSoDerp, that is exactly why i wanted to know

Answer (score 0):

So first I hope you are talking about an increase in percentage points and second that the winning probability is set back to 2% once you win before hitting the 70% winning chance. I guess your question is how likely it to loose n times in a row to directly hit the 70% winning probability right?

In such a case you need to loose 34 times in a row to reach a 70% chance of winning since $$2 + 2\cdot n \stackrel{!}{=} 70 \Leftrightarrow n = 34$$

So the odds to actually reach this scenario is $$P_1(loose) \cdot P_2(loose) \cdots \cdot P_{34}(loose) = 0.98 \cdot 0.96 \cdot \cdots \cdot 0.32 = 0.0000000024%$$

Therefore the probability that this happens is 0.00000024%